# Create US heat map with mouseover popup features and NO FLASH

Tags: flash, dictionary, heatmap

Currently am using an interactive flash map on my website, which displays different colors for different states of US based on some data. I also have a mouseover feature to display additional data when user hovers over a state.

Are there any tools to achieve the above functionality **without using flash** (mobile compatible). I'm ready to pay for those tools if needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a mobile compatible site, you'll have to use Javascript.

[JQuery](http://jquery.com/) is a great place to start if you've not done much with Javascript before.  It will give you fairly easy mechanisms to handle the mouseover events and the popups.

You can try to arrange all of the state images using HTML and CSS, but you might also want to look at the [HTML 5 Canvas element](http://diveintohtml5.info/canvas.html#divingin).  It works in most modern browsers, and there's [a hack](http://code.google.com/p/explorercanvas/) to make it work in IE.

Depending on how you do it, you may also want to learn about [image maps](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_map.asp).  There are lots of tools to help with the [creation of image maps](http://www.google.com/search?source=ig&hl=en&rlz=&=&q=image+map+for+us+map&btnG=Google+Search#sclient=psy&hl=en&safe=active&q=image+map+generator&aq=f&aqi=g3g-m1g-o1&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=&pbx=1&fp=84f34ab5383c7ee9).

**UPDATE**
I was working with some charts, and came across [this example](http://raphaeljs.com/australia.html) using a JS library called [Raphae](http://raphaeljs.com/)l.  This seems an awful lot like what you're looking for.

Also I realized as I was looking at that example that if you're coding for a mobile *touch screen* device (iPhone, iPad, Android, etc.), you won't have a "hover" event (for obvious reasons).  You might want to try to detect if the browser supports "hover", and if not, do your animations on "click" instead.

Comment: Arranging all the state images sounds cool. DO you know any place where I can get such image, with all states joined together?

Comment: I'd use that Raphael library, and then find a simple SVG file of the US, like this one:  http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a5/Map_of_USA_with_state_names.svg

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a [Google Visualization GeoChart](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart.html).

This is SVG-based; sorry, I don't know how limiting this is for mobile.

The place I fear you might get hung up is that the hover content may not be as flexible as you'd like.